# Using node.js experimental loaders with rollup

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

I am using `rollup` to bundle my Node.js applications - it allows me to deploy them in production as a single file without relying on `npm`.

I also happen to have my own custom loaders for some special format files that I import in my code by calling

`node --experimental-loader=./lib/txt-colormap-es-loader.mjs` and then doing

```js
import colormap from './colormaps/01.txt';
```

One of these is `handlebars` for which there is a special plugin in rollup.

But I also have my own custom formats with my own custom loaders.

Does anyone see any way I could make `rollup` work with my custom ES6 loader in Node.js short of writing a new plugin?

Comment: Not knowing anything about experimental loaders, my guess would be "no", since rollup doesn't execute any code, it processes dependencies via static analysis.

Comment: I am hoping for an eventual plugin, something that allows me to call a user-supplied function all files of given type? The JSON loader for example must do exactly that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but you can definitely write a plugin to handle your files. You can have a look at the implementation of the JSON loader for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I found a suboptimal solution without developing/publishing/maintaining a new `rollup` plugin - import the loader itself and call it manually on the file imported as a string. Importing as a string can be accomplished

- In development, before bundling, by

  https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-as-string
- In production, with rollup, by

  https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-string